# View Complete Asp.Net Web Configuration

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-config, iis-7.5

Is there a tool out there that can output an ASP.Net web applications's complete configuration. Obviously you have the web.config file at the level you are at, but this is inheriting from possibly numerous other web.configs all the way up to the machine.config. I would like to be able to view the complete configuration from all the way up the hierarchy.

I ask this as we have an application we are trying to get working beneath a SharePoint (2010) IIS  (7.5) site. We can get it working when we create a separate distinct IIS site and point directly at the physical files. However when we create a new virtual directory/application beneath a SharePoint (2010) site it just fails (Event log says KernelBase.dll crash). We've gone through the web.config and added/removed various elements but it is still not working. If I could capture the complete configuration of the same application from the 2 perspectives, that might help us diagnose the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a tool (doesn't mean one doesn't exist though) however we've had inheritance issues before as well. Is your base site running a different version of the .net framework? also check all web.config libraries listed and their versions. If anything requires in the site runs with a newer version say 4.0, it could cause issues or vice versa.
Try adding in the parent app this section around system.web config section:

<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">

<system.web>
..
</system.web>

</location>

however note that this will affect other applications. If this fixes it, but negatively affects your other apps then you may need to duplicate the parents removed settings into the child apps that need it.